# What does this method do on C# Math.Abs(sum - 1) < 1e-9 what is it? 1e-9

Tags: c#

What does this method do on C# Math.Abs(sum - 1) < 1e-9 what is it?  1e-9

```
 enter code here

 static void RightMain()
   {
    double x = 1.0 / 10;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    sum += x;
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(sum - 1) < 1e-9);
    }
```

Comment: return either true or false. Not sure what the actual question is here. Just run it and see for yourself?

Comment: it's `0.000000001`, short form of writing that number is `1e-9`

Comment: It (the `1e-9`) stands for "1.0 times ten to the power of minus 9".  It's known as "exponential notation".  It's appropriate for very large or very small numbers.  For example, the speed of light is about 2.998e8

Answer (score 0):

The [`Math.Abs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=netframework-4.7.2) method will return the absolute value (the "positive" value of the number) of `sum - 1`, and the value of `1e-9` is [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) that represents a value of 0.000000009.

The code you've posted will compare the absolute value of `sum - 1`, against 0.000000009.

Comment: Note to add that it will write `true` or `false` into the console